# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture

Tags: python, django, django-fixtures

I'm attempting to create a fixture from my development database data and storing it my test database. This data happens to be only one model. I ran the `dumpdata` command as such:

`python manage.py dumpdata minerals.mineral --all --indent=4 
--output=minerals/test_minerals/fixtures/test_mineral_data.json`

When attempting to run the `python manage.py test`, the following error is raised:

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture 
'../minerals/test_minerals/fixtures/test_mineral_data.json': 
Could not load minerals.Mineral(pk=872): UNIQUE constraint failed: minerals_mineral.name`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.fixtures

> By default, fixtures are only loaded into the default database.

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I was under the initial impression that fixtures were stored in an empty database when attempting to unit test but apparently that is incorrect? What can be done to emulate the data so I can test?

**tests.py**

```
class SearchFormResults(TestCase):

    fixtures = ['minerals/test_minerals/fixtures/test_mineral_data.json']

    def test_user_search_query_fail(self):
        response = self.client.get(
            reverse("minerals:search_list"), data={'query': 'Kryptonite'},
            HTTP_REFERRER=reverse(
                "minerals:letter_list", kwargs={'query': 'N'}
            ), follow=True
        )
```

**models.py**

```
class Mineral(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    image_filename = models.ImageField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    image_caption = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    formula = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    strunz_classification = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    crystal_system = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    unit_cell = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    crystal_symmetry = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    cleavage = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    mohs_scale_hardness = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    luster = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    streak = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    diaphaneity = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    optical_properties = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    refractive_index = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    crystal_habit = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    specific_gravity = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Are there no duplicates of `mineral.name` is fixture file? And it is not loaded in migrations or other test cases?

Comment: To initially populate my development database, I used a data migration. That migration removed all the duplicated data as I was iterating over the original JSON data.

There are no other test cases that are using a fixture.

Comment: So, is some django migration loading this data / fixture into database? Then data is already in the database before TestCase fixtures are run.

Comment: Stop using fixtures and start with https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ Fixtures in a long term projects are very problematic.